# What is VAN and how to transfer the file through VAN using JAVA?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

Actual I am in need of transferring the EDI files through VAN. But I don't know what is exactly the VAN means??. Is there any way to transfer the file through the VAN using Java ?? or using any external client(application) ??

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean **W**AN? And what have you tried searching for? What have you tried yourself? And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value-added network (VAN) is a private network provider that is hired by a company to facilitate electronic data interchange (EDI) or provide other network services.

So You can say VAN is dedicated private connection between two networks which cannot be accessed by other users. If your network uses TCP/IP above VAN then, normal socket programming using java would work fine.

Comment: Thank a lot. Can we use Apache FTP client to connect??

Comment: It depends upon Application protocol you are using. If its FTP , then Apache client FTP will work.

Comment: Ok, then I will ask for what protocol their using?? thanks